# Displaying associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am a Ruby on Rails newbie and had a question about the view logic in case of associated objects:

My models look similar to

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And what I want to display is something like a list of all the posts and the first three comments for each.

So, I kept the post contoller index action simple

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  #..
  def index 
    @posts = Post.find(:all)
  end
  #..
end
```

Now in the `views/posts/index.html.erb` I can do something like this **`@posts.comments`**
which I can loop for the first three entries. But How do I access functionality that is normally done in the model (in this case the associated model) like ordering, scoping etc. in the  view (or controller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid writing complex business login in the view. In this case, your execution is simple enough that you can write all the code in your view. It should look like this

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% @post.comments.all(:limit => 3, :order => "created_at DESC").each do |comment| %>
      do something
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

There are a couple of possibile improvements. First, use a named_scope.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :post
  named_scope :recent, proc { |limit| :limit => limit || 3, :order => "created_at DESC") }
  # you can also hard-code the limit value (ScottD)
  named_scope :recent, :limit => 3, :order => "created_at DESC"
end


<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% @post.comments.recent.each do |comment| %>
      do something
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I'm right, the .each can be removed.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% @post.comments.recent do |comment| %>
      do something
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you prefer, you can also define a custom relationship (this is for really complex relationships).

Comment: I would make some small changes to your example:
1) You don't need the proc on the named scope.  Just do named_scope :recent :limit => 3, :order...
2) In the view I would use a partial:
<%= render :partial "comment", :collection => @post.comments.recent %>
Rails will send the array returned by the named_scope and render the partial in a loop for you.

Comment: Thanks weppos and ScottD. Got it running perfectly. Just a newbie clarification needed. 
In the above code when the PostContoller loads @posts and the view/partail runs @post.comments.recent when are the sql calls being fired? Is there any way I can see this (traces etc.)?

Comment: The SQL is being executed by the full @post.comments.recent statement. The translation could be "call the recent comments associated to @post object". You can view the full SQL in you log/development.log file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a find method on the association which specified a limit like:

```
@post.comments.find(:all, :limit => 3)
```

in your view, or you can create another association in your Post model something like:

```
has_many :first_three_comments, :limit => 3, :class_name => "Comment"
```

and then you can just reference that association like

@post.first_three_comments.each do |comment| ...

Hope that helps.

Comment: will the extra association be faster/more performant than the named_scope solution mentioned in answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028830/displaying-associated-objects/1028873#1028873 ?

Comment: named scopes are a more elegant solution and supercede my solution.

named_scope :cheap, :conditions => { :price => 0..5 }
  named_scope :recent, lambda { |*args| {:conditions => ["released_at > ?", (args.first || 2.weeks.ago)]} }
  named_scope :visible, :include => :category, :conditions => { 'categories.hidden' => false }

http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope